# Passing lat lng to another activity in Android

Tags: android, google-maps, android-activity

I am trying to enable the user to long click on a map and, instead of creating a marker, the new activity should open. It should contain latitude and longitude, i.e. the location on which the user clicked.

I know data transfer is easy when I use dialogs, but I don't want to use dialog fragment in this part of my app.

MapActivity:

```
//Add marker on long click
final double finalLongitude = longitude;
final double finalLatitude = latitude;

mMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener() {
    // start SendMessageActivity need to add marker to message activity
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), DisplayLocationActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("latitude",""+ finalLatitude);
    intent.putExtra("longitude", "" + finalLongitude);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

DisplayLocationActivity:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_set_location);

    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    double lat = bundle.getDouble("latitude");
    double lng = bundle.getDouble("longitude");

    //display lat lng
    mLatDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.latTextViewDisplay);
    mLangDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lngTextViewDisplay);

    mLatDisplay.setText(String.valueOf(lat));
    mLangDisplay.setText(String.valueOf(lng));
}
```

My problem is this - when I start the app and click on the map, the newly opened activity displays the lat and lng as 0.0 no matter where on the map I clicked.

Comment: That means your `if (myLocation != null) {` not getting called. debug and check here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As see here [LatLng](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/LatLng):

> public final class LatLng extends Object implements Parcelable

Means `Latlng` class implements `Parcelable` interface, so we can pass it direclty using `Intent.putExtra` like:

```
@Override
public void onMapLongClick(LatLng arg) {
  intent.putExtra("Latlng", arg);
  ..
}
```

and get it in next Activity using `getExtras().getParcelable` like:

```
LatLng objLatLng=getIntent().getExtras().getParcelable("Latlng");
```

Now use `objLatLng` to show location coordinates in TextView's.

Comment: @Kemo: it's ok. i have just posted this answer to show other and easy way to share `LatLng ` object between components.Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You are passing the data as `String` but retrieving it as `double`.

Change

```
intent.putExtra("latitude",""+ finalLatitude);
intent.putExtra("longitude", "" + finalLongitude);
```

for

```
intent.putExtra("latitude", finalLatitude);
intent.putExtra("longitude", finalLongitude);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply Antonio, I now have the following problem - the lat/lng displays user's current location instead of the location on the map I clicked. I updated my code above.

Comment: Is `myLocation != null`?

Comment: myLocation != null is used when the device has not enabled GPS. If I set my GPS location enabled it shows my current location instead of the place on the map I clicked on.

Comment: Althought this answer solves your issue and minimises the changes in your code for it to work, @ρяσѕρєя K 's answer is better and must be the accepted answer

Answer (score 2):

In my case I am doing like this. First activity for sendinf intent...

```
LatLng center = mMap.getCameraPosition().target;
intent.putExtra("Latlng", center);
```

Second Activity.

```
Intent intent;
LatLng latlong =intent.getIntent().getExtras().getParcelable("Latlng");
```

Now you can get Latitude and Longitude from latlong Object

```
latlong.getlatitude;
latlong.getlongitude
```

Answer (score 1):

**You should write your `Intent` while passing data as this.**

```
  intent.putExtra("latitude", finalLatitude);
  intent.putExtra("longitude", finalLongitude);
```

Comment: That means your `if (myLocation != null) {` not getting called. debug and check here.

Answer (score 1):

Change the read code in the receiving activity to this:

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
double lat = Double.valueOf(bundle.getString("latitude"));
double lng = Double.valueOf(bundle.getString("longitude"));
```

Or pass the Extras as doubles in the first place :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
intent.putExtra("lat","" finalLatitude);
intent.putExtra("lng", ""  finalLongitude);
```

then get like,

```
double lat = Double.valueOf(bundle.getString("lat"));
double lng = Double.valueOf(bundle.getString("lng"));
```

Thanks.