# Get latitude and longitude from google maps' shared location in my own Android app

Tags: java, android, google-maps, latitude-longitude, getlocation

I'm trying to share a location from Google Maps to my own Android, I'm doing it with an Intent in my app and I successfully get the Intent in my app, but I'm getting something like this:

https://maps.app.goo.gl/SUeYVuEWd5u9Xn5B8

So, the problem is that I can't get latitude and longitude from this URL.

In my AndroidManifest I have and intent filter in the activity where I want to get the location

```
<activity
            android:name=".activities.MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
            </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Then, in my activity I receive the intent in this way

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
        String action = intent.getAction();
        String type = intent.getType();

        if(Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(action) && type != null) {
            if("text/plain".equals(type)) {
                String sharedText = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
                if(sharedText != null) {
                    //sharedText = https://maps.app.goo.gl/SUeYVuEWd5u9Xn5B8
                    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this);
                    List<Address> addressesList = geocoder.getFromLocationName(sharedText, 1);
                }
            }
        }
```

But the `addressesList` object has a size of 0 since I can't get the location from https://maps.app.goo.gl/SUeYVuEWd5u9Xn5B8

Whats is the best way to get latitude and longitude?

Comment: Would this related question help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/37183439/18422887

Comment: @Yrll I'm not implementing Google Maps SDK for Android, I took the shared link directly from Google Maps app installed in the device

Comment: You might want to check Google Maps Intents for Android. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/android-intents Also what are you passing to the Geocoder? Is it just a URL? How about just using Maps APIs?